# JSON incomplete variable

Tags: php, json, encoding, decoding

for some reason I have a problem getting a JSON input into PHP. Basically, I am importing a variable from a url-encoded JSON, the bit of code I have problem with looks like this:

```
"nearest_area": [ 
                 { 
                   "country": [
                     {"value": "Czech Republic"}
                   ],   
                  "region": [ 
                     {"value": "Moravskoslezsky Kraj" }
                 ]         
               } 
             ]
```

When I import and JSON_decode it in PHP, I used the exact same way of getting the two variables. For country I used

```
data->nearest_area[0]->country[0]->value;
```

and I got Czech Republic, for the other one I used region instead of country, but for some reason instead of Moravskoslezsky Kraj, I am always getting just the first word - "Moravskoslezsky".

The only reason I could think of what could be causing the problem is encoding. In fact, in Czech, the actual name of the region ("kraj") is "Moravskoslezský". I used the UTF8 decoding procedure and indeed I am getting the proper "ý" at the end instead of "y", but then it just skips the rest....

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Please also post more code for context of where you are using that value as output.

Comment: JSON data already comes encoded in utf-8. You don't want to convert it to utf-8 again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry I have figured it out, there was a problem with encoding the actual url.